# How to get the "Share" link in a content posted via Graph?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, share

I am creating an application that allows to publish content on a page of which I am administrator. I use the https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed with the access_token and other parameters relating to the content.

It works fine, but the post that appear on the wall hasn't got the "Share" link; it has only the "Comments" and "Like" links.

How do I get on these post also the "Share" link?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything about this with the api, facebook removed the share link on posts from applications some time ago. If you post to ALBUM_ID/photos or PAGE_ID/photos you still get the share link, you can use this as an alternative if you are posting pictures. Good luck.

Comment: I'm not posting pictures, but textual contents.
So there is no way to get the "Share" link, sending the post via an application?

Comment: No, not at this time. I don't think you get the share button even if you post a pure text status through the facebook page wall, only if you post a link or image.